# How do I effectively save a file to my directory of choice in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask

I have tried using different ways yet it fails
kindly help.

This is one of the ways. It does save the file unfortunately it is saved as 0kb

```
@app.route("/droid",methods=['GET','POST'])
def cloud_Upload():                                  
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect('/home')
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect('/home')
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        dicom_file = dcmread(file, force=True)
        dicom_file_metadata = dir(dicom_file)
        attributes = dir(dicom_file)
        path = 'C:/Users/malvinjohnny/Desktop/project_server/azure/'
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
        file.save(os.path.join( path,filename))
    return render_template('droid.html')
```

the line I'm using to save my files

```
file.save(os.path.join( path,filename))
```

Comment: You have to show us more code than this.  What is `file`?  What is `path`?  What is `filename`?

Comment: DON'T SHOUT PLEASE! [ask] and also [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what file is defined as, but using `open` is usually the way to go. See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

```
data = "stuff to write to file"
with open(filename, "w+") as file:  
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: have pasted  the full code

Comment: This is still valid code. in your example file is just the data of the file. You could probably put open in binary mode, and write the data using open. There are fancier ways to do this, but open is pretty easy.

Comment: with my code as seen above what do you think will feed in as data kindly come to my aid